# Plot the phase structure function of a phase screen by definition

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have already had a phase screen (a 2-D NxN matrix and LxL in size scale, ex: N = 256, L = 2 meters).

I would like to find phase structure function - D(r) defined by D(delta(r)) = <[x(r)-x(r+delta(r))]^2> (<.> is ensemble averaging, r is position in phase screen in meter, x is phase value at a point in phase screen, delta(r) is variable and not fix) in Matlab program. Do you have any suggestion for my purpose?

P/S: I tried to calculate D(r) via the autocorrelation (is defined as B(r)), but this calculation still remaining some approximations. Therefore, I want to calculate precisely the result of D(r). May you please [see this image to better understand the definition of D(r) and B(r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l05O.jpg). Below is my function code to calculate B(r).

```
% Code copied from "Numerical Simulation of Optical Wave Propagation with Examples in Matlab",
% by Jason D. Schmidt, SPIE Press, SPIE Vol. No.: PM199
% listing 3.7, page 48.
% (Schmidt defines the ft2 and ift2 functions used in this code elswhere.)
function D = str_fcn2_ft(ph, mask, delta)
    % function D = str_fcn2_ft(ph, mask, delta)

    N = size(ph, 1);
    ph = ph .* mask;

    P = ft2(ph, delta);
    S = ft2(ph.^2, delta);
    W = ft2(mask, delta);
    delta_f = 1/(N*delta);
    w2 = ift2(W.*conj(W), delta_f);

    D = 2 * ft2(real(S.*conj(W)) - abs(P).^2, delta) ./ w2 .*mask;`



%fire run
N = 256; %number of samples  
L = 16;  %grid size [m]
delta = L/N; %sample spacing [m]
F = 1/L; %frequency-domain grid spacing[1/m]
x = [-N/2 : N/2-1]*delta; 
[x y] = meshgrid(x);
w = 2; %width of rectangle
%A = rect(x/2).*rect(y/w);
A = lambdaWrapped;
%A = phz;
mask = ones(N); 
%perform digital structure function 
C = str_fcn2_ft(A, mask, delta);
C = real(C);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1) Please edit your question so that it doesn't hurt the eyes (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). 2) Define your notations (what is `B(r)`?) 3) Share your efforts and explain your thoughts. Why can't you use autocorrelation? 4) Sharing a snippet of code wont hurt. Although annoying to read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask makes a few good points.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's still hard for me to explain everything in details with tons of math functions. I tried to edit my question to be more understandable. I hope everyone will see my points.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code into your question, don't post images of code. It's harder to read, and impossible to copy-paste to run it ourselves. -- Also: what is `delta(r)`? Is this a fixed value? `r` is a position in the 2D space? I know, it sucks posting equations here...

Comment: I'd just like to point out that OP's function D = str_fcn2_ft(ph, mask, delta) is taken verbatim from Numerical Simulation of Optical Wave Propagation with Examples in Matlab, Jason D. Schmidt, SPIE Press, SPIE Vol. No.: PM199, listing 3.7, page 48. Elsewhere Schmidt defines ft2 and ift2 functions used in the code listed above.

Answer (score 0):

One way of directly computing this function D(r) is through random sampling: you pick two random points on your screen, determine their distance and phase difference squared, and update an accumulator:

```
phi = rand(256,256)*(2*pi); % the data, phase

N = size(phi,1); % number of samples  
L = 16;  % grid size [m]
delta = L/N; % sample spacing [m]

D = zeros(1,sqrt(2)*N); % output function
count = D; % for computing mean

for n = 1:1e6 % find a good amount of points here, the more points the better the estimate
   coords = randi(N,2,2);
   r = round(norm(coords(1,:) - coords(2,:)));
   if r<1
      continue % skip if the two coordinates are the same
   end
   d = phi(coords(1,1),coords(1,2)) - phi(coords(2,1),coords(2,2));
   d = mod(abs(d),pi); % you might not need this, depending on how A is constructed
   D(r) = D(r) + d.^2;
   count(r) = count(r) + 1;
end
I = count > 0;
D(I) = D(I) ./ count(I); % do not divide by 0, some bins might not have any samples
I = count < 100;
D(I) = 0; % ignore poor estimates

r = (1:length(D)) * delta;
plot(r,D)
```

If you need even more precision, consider interpolating. Compute random coordinates as floating-point values, and interpolate the phase to get the values in between samples. `D` then needs to be longer, indexed as `round(r*10)` or something like that. You will need many more random samples to fill up that much larger accumulator.